# Calculate intersection between two points on a graph Javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates

Given the below graphic, how would I provide a function pairs of x,y coordinates, and return a new x,y coordinate based on the pair's x,y intersection on the graph (preserving the order the original x,y pairs were given)?

[image]

Comment: You mean `([x,_], [_, y]) => [x, y]` or `([_, y], [x,_]) => [x, y]`? (Notice that you seem to have swapped the two results for A-B in your graphic, they're inconsistent with A-C and B-C)

Comment: Why is (6,2) considered "A->B" while (-6,8) is considered "B->A"?!?

Comment: @iAmOren I think I mixed them up

Comment: Mixed - yeah - can you fix?
Do you want the "x" to determine the left side, and the "y" to determine the right side?
Like so:
New Point (x from A, y from B) = "A->B",
and:
New Point (x from B, y from A) = "B->A"?

Comment: @iAmOren that is exactly correct, I am sorry for the mistake

Comment: Ok, please see my answer below.  
If it pleases you, please up-vote and select it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the correct labeling of intersection points and the logic to deduce them - as per your agreement with my assumption.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code snippet doesn't seem to allow `console.table`, so here it is with `console.log` instead:

```js
var points=[
  {name:"A", x:6, y:8},
  {name:"B", x:-6, y:2},
  {name:"C", x:4, y:-4}
];

function intersection(pntsArr) {
  var returnValue=[];
  for(var i=0; i<pntsArr.length-1; i++) {
    for(var j=i+1; j<pntsArr.length; j++) {
      returnValue.push( {
        name:pntsArr[i].name+"->"+pntsArr[j].name,
        x:pntsArr[i].x,
        y:pntsArr[j].y
      } );
      returnValue.push( {
        name:pntsArr[j].name+"->"+pntsArr[i].name,
        x:pntsArr[j].x,
        y:pntsArr[i].y
      } );
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}

console.log(intersection(points));
```

Should work with any number of points.
Could produce duplicate points, depending on input.

Comment: really cool and simple, i'll upvote - would be really nice to see an es6 example with better time complexity however

Comment: I don't know how to do that:  If I use two `for(var point of points)`, I'd have to get the index  and compare...  `map` will get an array of `points.length`, double `forEach` will double(...) the results == two of each...

Comment: Can you give an example of the direction you'd like to see an es6 improvement?

Comment: Sometimes, old school rules... :)